# Are [sleep] and [sleep-mode] tags the same? Merge?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

There is no description for these tags, are they referring to the same thing? If so then should they be merged? [sleep-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleep-mode) would appear more popular, although to be honest I prefer the shorter [sleep](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleep) and personally I never use the term "sleep-mode", always "sleep".

Comment: I guess you could possibly argue that `sleep-mode` is when the device is sleeping (screen off and such) and `sleep` could refer to other things. It appears to be used for a couple of questions about sleep patterns and alarms, so `sleep-mode` wouldn't make sense there.

Comment: @eldarerathis In that case `sleep` is not a good tag, someone's sleeping is not really relevant :P

Comment: @MatthewRead: Oh yeah. IMHO `sleep` is kind of an icky tag for that reason. It's easy to misuse, whereas `sleep-mode` is easier to understand.

Comment: I agree, `sleep-mode` is a better tag

Comment: I had assumed that `sleep` and `sleep-mode` referred to the same thing (ie. computer sleep mode). To be honest, I never imagined that a `sleep` tag, on a technical computer-related site, would refer to anything else. So, as stated, I would agree that `sleep` is not a good tag in this respect. (Should it be removed?) `sleep-mode` avoids any ambiguity.